# How do I print a json value sent by AJAX request in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to print a `json` value which was sent using AJAX in my PHP server script. This is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="date" id="date" name="date">
<button id="fetch">Button</button>
```

**JS**:

```
const months = {"01":"Jan",
                "02":"Feb",
                "03":"Mar",
                "04":"Apr",
                "05":"May",
                "06":"Jun",
                "07":"Jul",
                "08":"Aug",
                "09":"Sep",
                "10":"Oct",
                "11":"Nov",
                "12":"Dec"};

let obj = {"key1":["abc","def"],"key2":[["123abc","saju242"]]};

function fetch(){
    return $.ajax({
                url: '/server.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'json',
                data:{
                     "date": JSON.stringify(date_splitted[2]+" "+
                     months[date_splitted[1]]+", "+date_splitted[0]),
                     "obj": JSON.stringify(obj)
                },
                cache: false
    });
}

document.getElementById('fetch').addEventListener('click',async function(){
    let response = await fetch();
    alert(response);
})
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:',TRUE);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["date"]));
    var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["obj"])));

    var_dump($_POST); //this is empty, why??
?>
```

When I execute the code, I keep getting an error,

> **Warning**:  Undefined array key "date"

> **Deprecated**:  stripslashes(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

I tried printing the `$_POST` array, but it's empty. But I am sending the correct `key => value` pair. Why is my array key undefined? Please help me.

Comment: don't `JSON.stringify` the request body

Answer (score 0):

The warning Undefined array key  `"date"` is occurring because you are trying to access an array element with the key `"date"` when it is not set in the `$_POST` array. This may be happening because the `data` property in your AJAX request is not properly sending the key "date".

To fix this issue, you can modify your AJAX request code to send the `date` value as a separate key-value pair in the `data` object. Here's an example:

```
function fetch(){
const dateInput = document.getElementById("date");
const selectedDate = dateInput.value; // Assuming the date input is of type "date"

const date_splitted = selectedDate.split("-");
const dateFormatted = `${date_splitted[2]} ${months[date_splitted[1]]}, ${date_splitted[0]}`;

return $.ajax({
    url: '/server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'json',
    data:{
        "date": dateFormatted,
        "obj": JSON.stringify(obj)
    },
    cache: false
});
}
```

Note that the above code assumes that the date input field has an id of `"date"`. You can modify this based on your HTML code.

> Regarding the warning Deprecated: `stripslashes()`: Passing null to
> parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated, this occurs
> because `stripslashes()` is being called with a `null` value. This can
> happen if `$_POST["date"]` is not set. To fix this warning, you can
> check if `$_POST["date"]` is set before calling `stripslashes()`.

Here's an example:

```
if (isset($_POST["date"])) {
echo json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["date"]));
}
if (isset($_POST["obj"])) {
    var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["obj"])));
}
```

This will only call `stripslashes()` if the `$_POST` array has a key `"date"` or `"obj"`.

Comment: It doesn't print anything when I use your code

Comment: Did You Include the CDN link for Jquery in your Header?